# Android 7 iframe video 'Refused to display' in WebView

Tags: android, video, iframe, twitter, webview

I have and application, which displays html content from other sources. This content may contain iframe embedded videos. For special case of twitter videos the behavior is different and video remains blank after running.

The logcat shows message:

```
Refused to display  'videoUrlHere' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors *".", source: about:blank (0)
```

Example url is: https://twitter.com/i/videos/tweet/840948416742117377?embed_source=clientlib&player_id=0&rpc_init=1&language_code=en

The interesting thing is that this approach works on android 5 and lower.

Loading of content

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", mHtmlSource.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Initialization of WebView:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new InjectedAppObject(), "InjectedAppObject");
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
```

Headers added to html:

```
<html lang=\"cs\" dir=\"ltr\">
<head>
<meta charset=\"utf-8\">
<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"\">
<meta name=\"description\" content=\"\">
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Security-Policy\" content=\"default-src * data: \'unsafe-inline\' \'unsafe-eval\'; frame-ancestors *; \">
<meta name=\"robots\" content=\"index,follow\">
  <title>App title</title>
  <link href=\"file:///android_asset/html/css/style.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
  <script src=\"file:///android_asset/html/js/jquery.min.js\"></script>
  <script src=\"file:///android_asset/html/js/app.js\"></script>
  <script src=\"file:///android_asset/html/js/disposable-iframe.min.js\"></script>
<script src=\"file:///android_asset/html/js/iframe.js\"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: did you found the solution

Comment: Hi. It is long ago so i am not sure if i remember correctly. I think that problem was that content was https but contained unsecure references. Android 5 seems to be handling this issue different way than later versions.